# Tomcat ignores settings - maxThreads maxConnections

Tags: windows, tomcat

I am doing stress testing with 100 users.

```
  <Connector port="7080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" maxThreads="1500"
      connectionTimeout="20000" acceptCount="1000" maxConnections="1000"
      minSpareThreads="80"
      maxSpareThreads="160"
      compression="on"
      compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain"
      redirectPort="8443" />
```

When i change `maxThreads`m `maxConnections` and `acceptCount` all to **1** I still get the same performance (Unresponsive after 70users)

I only have one other connector configured, AJP

```
<Connector port="7089" protocol="AJP/1.3" maxThreads="10500" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Why are configuration parameters ignored or do not make any difference?